# Push Docker Image to Private Repo In Openshift

Tags: openshift

I am trying to push the docker image to the private jfrog repo.But it is pushing openshift repo by S2i.

apiVersion: v1
items:

- apiVersion: image.openshift.io/v1
  kind: ImageStream
  metadata:
  annotations:
  openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
  openshift.io/image.insecureRepository: "true"
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
  app: bulkhold-s2i
  name: bulkhold-s2i
  spec:
  output:
  to:
  kind: DockerImage
  name: 'bulkhold-s2i:latest'
  dockerImageRepository: *****/it-mfg/bulkhold
  pushSecret:
  name: itmfg-docker-dev-local
  status:
  dockerImageRepository: ******/it-mfg/bulkhold
  tag: latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put `spec.output` in your BuildConfig*1 instead of imagestream.

*1: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/cicd/builds/managing-build-output.html